# Orienting line labels to graticules in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, labeling

I have been trying to add labels to a map that are oriented parallel to the graticule lines
In ArcGIS, with Maplex, it is simple [link](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-text/orienting-line-labels.htm), but in QGIS I cant find any way to do this.

Comment: Maybe somehing like this can work: https://geosupportsystem.se/2020/07/08/bojda-etiketter-i-qgis/

Comment: This works great for lines and polygons, its a shame that with points there is no curved option when placing labels, but still, the results are quite nice.

Answer (score 1):

**!! This only works if the point layer is in a unprojected CRS, because only then will QGIS reproject the created straight line on-the-fly into the curve on the map that follows the graticules of the map-CRS. !!**
[image: Overview]
Using the geometry generator create a line that consists of the original point and a point offset to the east or west (wherever you prefer your labels to go), densifying the geometry count makes for a nice arc. The code looks as follows:

```
densify_by_count(
    make_line(
        make_point(
        x($geometry) + 0.02,
        y($geometry)
        ),
        make_point(
        x($geometry) + 5,
        y($geometry)
        )
    ),
    5
)
```

[image: Options in the label panel]
Changes to X-offset need to be done in respect to the scale of your map because they are in the unit of the layer (in this case degrees). It is also important to adjust label overrun, label anchoring and the label placement method according to your maps needs.

Comment: Crimea is a part of Ukraine!

Comment: Oh sorry, just pulled Natural Earth data to generate a base map. Seems that they don't have disputed borders in this data, which I downloaded years ago.

Comment: Nice solution, like it!